# Reasons Against Empty Paragraphs in HTML

Tags: html, css

EDIT: Rephrased question.

Other than being bad practice, what other reasons are there against empty paragraphs in HTML?

ORIGINAL:

**Background**

Currently to add a nicely space paragraph in our CMS you press Enter key twice. I don't like empty paragraphs because they seem unnecessary to me. If you want a new paragraph, just press Enter and space it with CSS. If you want to write just below some text (e.g. to display code), then do a line break with Shift+Enter.

**Question**

Is there any very good reason in not allowing empty paragraphs? Is there a standard here? Seems like I just have a philosophical issue right now -- i.e. using empty paragraphs probably won't make page viewing faster or save that much space.

Comment: I see it as two paragraphs, not three with the middle one being empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I've learnt the heard way is that any time you have a WYSIWYG editor for a web page, you stand a risk of ending up with poor quality HTML.

It doesn't matter how good the editor is, or how well trained your people are to use it, you will end up with bad code.

They'll click the 'bold' button instead of selecting your sub-title class. They'll create spurious paragraph tags rather than line breaks. And I've had to explain to one person several times why it's a bad idea to use multiple spaces to indent stuff.

Even when people are very good at using the editor and understand the implications, you'll still get things like stray markup setting styles and then unsetting them without any content, because if you (for example) make a word bold and then delete it, it generally doesn't delete the bold tags, and no-one thinks to switch to the HTML view to check.

The basic problem is that when you make it easy to use like a word processor, people will treat it like a word processor, and the underlying code becomes completely irrelevant to them. Their job is to produce content that looks good, and as long as they can achieve that, they don't generally care for how the code looks.

The good thing is that there is a solution. In general, the people generating the content are the same people who care the most about SEO. If you emphasise that there might be SEO consequences to poor quality HTML, I find that they suddenly care a lot more about the code they're generating. They still don't generally have the skills to fix it when they've broken it, but it does seem to make people take more care to follow the rules.

To directly answer your question, I don't think it's a disaster to have empty paragraph tags like that. It's preferable not to though, and you need to consider how the content would look semantically to a search engine - it may cause the search engine to see the two paragraphs of content as being less connected to each other than they should be. This may affect how it weights the content of each paragraph when it comes to deciding its page rank. In truth, it's unlikely to be a huge difference; in fact, I'd say it's probably very tiny, but in a competitive world, it could be enough to push you down a few places. There are probably other more important SEO issues for you to deal with, but as they say, every little helps.

Comment: `It doesn't matter how good the editor is...`, No! it has everything to do with how good the editor is.  The better the editor, the less bloat and the better the translations are from what the user typed to what should be saved.  If you don't like spaces at the beginning, then your regex/editor is broken, not the user.

Answer (score 0):

By styling paragraphs with CSS, you can change the way paragraphs are styled easily in future.

For example, you might want to style differently if the user is browsing on a mobile device, or you might just decide that you want to add more or less space between paragraphs (using attributes like `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` on the `p` tag I guess) because it just looks better that way. If the spacing is done with extra `p` tags it'd be a lot harder to change.

I expect that things like screen readers for the visually impaired would deal with CSS-styled paragraphs better than if the structure of the page is changed by adding empty paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

There are times when you have a CSS styling a particular element in your case a paragraph. IF you will use empty paragraph they will unneccesarily pick up that styling which might not be needed.